# determining var type from prompt command and if else statement

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write this exercise from a book:

> Write a program to ask yourself, using prompt, what the value of 2 + 2
>   is. If the answer is "4", use alert to say something praising. If it
>   is "3" or "5", say "Almost!". In other cases, say something mean.

I made this attempt:

```
var input = "" || 'number'
prompt ("How many is 2+2 ?", input)
if (input = 4)
  print ("Awesome !");
else if (input = 3 || input = 5)
  print ("Close !");
else if (input = 'number'
  print ("wrong number");
else if (input = 'random text')
  print ("use numbers only!")
```

I know it is wrong. This is I intended to do:

- I need to determine the type of `var`, not just the value. I need to make `var` either number or string (according to `typeof`). Why ? For `prompt` imput, because below `else if` condition, will be based on which type was inputted.
- I know that exercise didn't asked it, but I want make it superior.

Comment: To get you started off, you use `==` to test if something is equal to something else, not `=`.

Comment: actually, use `===` ;)

Comment: The `prompt` input is *always* a string. Do you mean `typeof` something else?

Comment: Also `var input = "" || 'number'` will always return `'number'`. Why not simply set `var number = null;`?

Comment: @insertusernamehere the input var is used as the default text for the prompt, so you'd be better off with `var input = 'Enter your guess';` or something.

Comment: @IvanKuckir It looks a lot like me like Rapier *is* learning Javascript.

Comment: @Grim... Ah cool. Never used `prompt`. But still `var input = 'number';` would be enough then. Oh you've updated your comment, too. :)

Comment: Go for a Switch...it's simpler

Answer (score 3):

`=` is assignment. `==` is comparison.

To convert the string that `prompt` gives you to a number, use `parseInt(input,10)` - that said, JavaScript will typecast for you, so there's no real need here. You can even tell if the user entered something that isn't a number by testing `isNaN(input)` for your "use numbers only" result.

So something like this:

```
var input = parseInt(prompt("How much is 2 + 2?",""),10);
if( input == 4) alert("Awesome!");
else if( input == 3 || input == 5) alert("Almost!");
else if( input == 10) alert("No GLaDOS, we're working in Base 10 here.");
else if( input == 42) alert("That may be the answer to Life, the Universe and Everything, but it's still wrong.");
else if( isNaN(input)) alert("Use numbers only please!");
else alert("You are wrong!");
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd personally suggest:

```
var guess = parseInt(prompt('What is 2 + 2?'), 10);

switch (guess) {
    case 4:
        console.log('Well done!');
        break;
    case 3:
    case 5:
        console.log('Almost!');
        break;
    default:
        console.log('Seriously? No.');
        break;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/JZfM3/).

Or, to be more functional about it:

```
function answerMath (sum) {
    var actual = eval(sum),
        guess = parseInt(prompt('What is ' + sum + '?'),10);
    if (guess === actual) {
        console.log('Well done!');
    }
    else if (guess + 1 === actual || guess - 1 === actual) {
        console.log('Almost!');
    }
    else {
        console.log('Seriously? No.');
    }
}

answerMath ('2*3');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/JZfM3/1/).

Note that while `eval()` is the *only* means I could think of in this situation to evaluate the sum passed to the function as a string, I'm not entirely sure it's a good recommendation (albeit `eval()` has more bad press than it perhaps deserves, though it *does* present risks).

Comment: You could pull the operator out of the sum with Regex and use a switch to do the calculation.

Comment: True, but that gets messy (and quickly!) if there's more than two numbers to be operated upon.

Answer (score 1):

In most programming languages, `=` is assignment, and `==` tests for equality. So

`a = 4` assigns the number 4 to the variable a. But `a == 4` checks to see if a is equal to 4.

So for your code, you'd need:

```
var input = "" || 'number'
prompt ("How many is 2+2 ?", input)
if (input == 4)
  print ("Awesome !");
else if (input == 3 || input == 5)
  print ("Close !");
else if (input == 'number')
  print ("wrong number");
else if (input == 'random text')
  print ("use numbers only!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to build on David Thomas's answer a little, because if you wanted to make it better, you could easily turn it into a little game.

```
var numa = Math.round(Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1);
var numb = Math.round(Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1);
var answer = numa + numb;
var guess = parseInt(prompt('What is ' + numa + ' + ' + numb + '?'), 10);

switch (guess) {
    case answer:
        alert('Well done!');
        break;
    case (answer - 1):
    case (answer + 1):
        alert('Almost!');
        break;
    default:
        alert('Seriously? No.');
        break;
}
```

Further things you could do would be to include a timer to see how long the user took to answer the question, and ask them if they way to play again when they get it right.

Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6U6eN/